# Is /razorqt/ available for saucy as a desktop environment?

Tags: desktop-environments

Found out and started to fall in love for Razor QT all over again.

- Is it available for 13.10?
- If So, how do I install?

Guess, you can put that under 'not added-yet '.
by [this guy](https://launchpad.net/~adconrad), apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes **razorqt** is available for Saucy(Ubuntu 13.10),

*Step 1:* Open a terminal<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:razor-qt
```

*Step 2:* Now, as a one-off, you should tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the PPA you just added:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

*Step 3:* Now you're ready to start installing rasor-qt from the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install razorqt
```

Comment: [at]Avinash Raji  Seemed to fail to fetch the repository : [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6585915/)  [Add date] 16th Decem~13.